# Pick the records which has the flag either X or Y, but not the records which has both X and Y from a SQL table

Tags: sql, sql-server, azure-sql-server

I have a table like this

```
AID     B       C   
2471    D471    X
2471    D471    Y

2471    E471    X

2471    F471    Y

2472    D471    X
2472    D471    X

2473    E471    Y
2473    E471    Y

2474    F471    Y
```

I need to pick the AID which has either X or Y by grouping A and B, 
but it should not pick the records which have X as well as Y when we grouped by A and B

Expected Output

```
AID     B       C
2471    E471    X

2471    F471    Y

2472    D471    X
2472    D471    X

2473    E471    Y
2473    E471    Y

2474    F471    Y
```

If you have any questions about this query, please let me know.

Scripts to create a table and insert data

```
CREATE TABLE tablename
(
    [A] int
    , [B] varchar(10)
    , [C] varchar(5)
);

INSERT INTO tablename
    ([A], [B], [C])
VALUES
    (2471, 'D471', 'X'),
    (2471, 'D471', 'Y'),
    (2471, 'E471', 'X'),
    (2471, 'F471', 'Y'),
    (2472, 'D471', 'X'),
    (2472, 'D471', 'X'),
    (2473, 'E471', 'Y'),
    (2473, 'E471', 'Y'),
    (2474, 'F471', 'Y')
;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming that the `C` column can only contain the values `X` and `Y`, you should be able to just check the distinct count:

```
WITH cte AS (
    SELECT A, B
    FROM tablename
    GROUP BY A, B
    HAVING COUNT(DISTINCT C) = 1
)

SELECT t1.A, t1.B, t1.C
FROM tablename t1
INNER JOIN cte t2
    ON t1.A = t2.A AND t1.B = t2.B;
```

[image: screen capture of demo below]

### Demo

Comment: Sorry, I forgot to mention that point.. not only X and Y, C column can have other values as well. I just tried your query by giving 'where c in ('X','Y')' inside the CTE as well as outside CTE, it is working fine.. thank you

Answer (score 1):

You can use `not exists`.  Assuming X and Y are the only values:

```
select t.*
from tablename t
where not exists (select 1
                  from tablename t2
                  where t2.a = t.a and
                        t2.b = t.b and
                        t2.c <> t.c
                 );
```

With an index on `tablename(a, b, c)`, this is likely to have the best performance.  In addition, it easily lets you fetch all the columns in the row.